# Bitwise invert a string and send it to a socket

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

how would I invert the bits for a given alphanumeric string and pass it to a socket function?

```
s = '1q2w3e4r'
stbin = ''

#String to binary
stbin = ''.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in s)

#Bitwise invert
stbin = ''.join('1' if x == '0' else '0' for x in stbin)

...

socket.sendall(stbin)
```

Such that the TCP packets data is:
`ce 8e cd 88 cc 9a cb 8d`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use strings to do this when there are operators available to work directly on the relevant integer values:

```
s = '1q2w3e4r'

print(' '.join([f'{ord(c)^255:2x}' for c in s]))
```

**Output:**

```
ce 8e cd 88 cc 9a cb 8d
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to send the string's inverted bytes rather than their hexadecimal representation, you can do it even simpler:

```
stbin = bytes(ord(x)^255 for x in s)
socket_instance.sendall(stbin)
```